# Filter strings with regex

Tags: regex, rust

I need to filter (select) strings that follow certain rules, print them and count the number filtered strings. The input is a big string and I need to apply the following rules on each line:

1. line must not contain any of `ab`, `cd`, `pq`, or `xy`
2. line must contain any of the vowels
3. line must contain a letter that repeats itself, like `aa`, `ff`, `yy` etc

I'm using the `regex` crate and it provides [`regex::RegexSet`](https://docs.rs/regex/1.3.1/regex/struct.RegexSet.html) so I can combine multiple rules. The rules I added are as follows

```rust
    let regexp = regex::RegexSet::new(&[
        r"^((?!ab|cd|pq|xy).)*",         // rule 1
        r"((.)\1{9,}).*",                // rule 3
        r"(\b[aeiyou]+\b).*",            // rule 2
    ])
```

But I don't know how to use these rules to filter the lines and  iterate over them.

```rust
pub fn p1(lines: &str) -> u32 {
    lines
      .split_whitespace().filter(|line| { /* regex filter goes here */ })
      .map(|line| println!("{}", line))
      .count() as u32
}
```

Also the compiler says that the crate doesn't support look-around, including look-ahead and look-behind.

Comment: I don't know Rust so I can't help you with the second part but if you can use Lookaheads, [one regex pattern](https://regex101.com/r/qlmuKu/1) would do the job: `^(?!.*(?:ab|cd|pq|xy))(?=.*[aeiou])(?=.*([a-z])\1).+$`.

Comment: Do you _need_ to use a regex? It seems the rules can be reduced to list of sequences that should be contained and list of sequences that should not.

Comment: @raindev How will you express rule 3 in the question in your list o sequences?

Comment: @HossainAdnan You can include pairs of all the letters in the alphabet into the list of sequences that should be contained.

Comment: @raindev you’re not serious are you? And there’s no guarantee that the letters are ASCII only too.

Comment: You use backreferences (rule 3) and lookaround (rule 1), so this set of regular expressions will not be compiled. Besides the three rules seem not to be best fit by regular expressions (even if they were compilable). If you just want to get a working set of regular expressions to work than call `unwrap()` on the result of `RegexSet::new` to get the compiled RegexSet and use the filter expression `regexp.matches(line).iter().count() == 3` (all three rules must match).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking to use a single regex, then doing this via the `regex` crate (which, by design, and as documented, does not support look-around or backreferences) is probably not possible. You could use a `RegexSet`, but implementing your third rule would require using a regex that lists every repetition of a Unicode letter. This would not be as bad if you were okay limiting this to ASCII, but your comments suggest this isn't acceptable.

So I think your practical options here are to either use a library that supports fancier regex features (such as [`fancy-regex`](https://crates.io/crates/fancy-regex) for a pure Rust library, or [`pcre2`](https://crates.io/crates/pcre2) if you're okay using a C library), or writing just a bit more code:

```
use regex::Regex;

fn main() {
    let corpus = "\
baz
ab
cwm
foobar
quux
foo pq bar
";

    let blacklist = Regex::new(r"ab|cd|pq|xy").unwrap();
    let vowels = Regex::new(r"[aeiouy]").unwrap();
    let it = corpus
        .lines()
        .filter(|line| !blacklist.is_match(line))
        .filter(|line| vowels.is_match(line))
        .filter(|line| repeated_letter(line));
    for line in it {
        println!("{}", line);
    }
}

fn repeated_letter(line: &str) -> bool {
    let mut prev = None;
    for ch in line.chars() {
        if prev.map_or(false, |prev| prev == ch) {
            return true;
        }
        prev = Some(ch);
    }
    false
}
```

Playground link: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=c0928793474af1f9c0180c1ac8fd2d47